# Can you store a JS object in a SharedArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, sharedarraybuffer

I need to share an object between a client side application and a web worker and I heard about SharedArrayBuffers. This is what I'd like to do.

main.js

```
let myWorker = new Worker('/worker.js')
let mySab = new SharedArrayBuffer(1024)
let myObj = { foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo' }
// Save 'myObj' to 'mySab'
worker.postMessage(sab)
```

worker.js

```
self.onmessage = (e) => {
    let myObj = BLANK // Get 'myObj' from SharedArrayBuffer
}
```

Is this possible? The examples I've seen of ShareArrayBuffers only ever save numbers in the buffer. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: No. (`Shared`)`ArrayBuffer`s hold binary data, not objects.

Comment: "*I need to share an object*" - what exactly do you mean by that? You can easily *send* the object to the web worker, who will receive a clone of the data.

Comment: You would use a `SharedArrayBuffer` only when you really need multi-threaded access to shared memory. With all the problems that can cause.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I know about sending it as a clone, just wondering if sharing was possible with an object or not. Makes sense that it only holds binary.

Comment: No, it is not possible for objects to be shared. This would mean that object access would have to be implemented thread-safe, which it isn't. Share by communicating (through messages) between your workers, instead of attempting to communicate by sharing memory.

Comment: There is [this project](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/buffer-backed-object) you may want to have a look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `SharedArrayBuffer`s only store binary data. You can only send copies of objects via the built-in `postMessage` function.

Sources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: can't you convert the Object to binary and vice-versa in the Worker?

Comment: I'm very confused as well. You'd thin kyou can JSON stringify and then TextEncode it to a binary array. I'm just not sure how to do this...

Comment: @Pete. 0

At this point you've serialized the object, so the main and worker threads are not SHARING the same object. Changes on one side will not be visable on the other side